# disable past dates on datepicker "without using JQuery UI"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to disable past dates from the current date on a datepicker, without using JQuery UI? I tried few posts for similar question but was unable to achieve it, Below is what I tried

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
 href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
});
</script>

<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
<input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text"/>
<span class="add-on">
  <i  data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
  </i>
</span>
```

I also tried

```
$("datetimepicker2").datepicker({ changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showOn: 'none', showButtonPanel: true,  minDate:'0d' });
```

and

```
 $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Comment: Done, I was able to do this below is the code:

$(function(){
        
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
            startDate: '-0m'
            //endDate: '+2d'
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $('#sDate1').text($('#datepicker1').data('date'));
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker('hide');
        });
              
    });

Answer (score 3):

Problem fixed :)

Below is the working code

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: '-0m'
        //endDate: '+2d'
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
        $('#sDate1').text($('#datepicker').data('date'));
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide');
    });

})
```